# Python Wheel creation, I don't get the description of the package in WinPython

Tags: python, package, setup.py, python-wheel

I am creating a wheel installation for a python (3.6 ) package I have done.
Everything works well except a small thing : when I drag and drop the file.wheel in WinPython ( WinPython Control Panel ) I don't see the description of my package
( the one I have put in setup.py in the 'description' key )
I have also a long_description on a rst file... where do I see it once the package is installed ?

I don't see also the description for my package in the list of the installed package... :-(

Any ideas ?

Thanks
Christophe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to see a description in WinPython Control Panel, add it manually in your `...\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\winpython\data\packages.ini` file.

there is now official/mandatory description included in an installed package, the closest workaround would be to do "pip search your_package" to get the description of "your_package" from pypi

see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_search/

... maybe pip show is even better:

```
C:>pip show winpython
Name: winpython
Version: 1.10.20180404
Summary: WinPython distribution tools, including WPPM
Home-page: http://winpython.github.io/
Author: Pierre Raybaut
Author-email: pierre.raybaut@gmail.com
License: MIT
```

Comment: Thank you @stonebig !!
I have edited the packages.ini file and of course that works...
Now the question is : why WinPython doesn't update that file itself when updating the list of the package??
"pip show my_package" works well and display the correct "Summary" as expected...

Comment: Nobody felt enough the pain to create that optional function. and maybe shall the "added" names be put in a complementary file in .settings